# Sending Error message in Spring websockets

Tags: spring, stomp, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I am trying to send error messages in Spring websockets with STOMP over SockJS.

I am basically trying to achieve which is being done [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-user-destination).

This is my Exception Handler

```
@MessageExceptionHandler
@SendToUser(value = "/queue/error",broadcast = false)
public ApplicationError handleException(Exception message) throws ApplicationError {
        return  new ApplicationError("test");
}
```

And I am subscribing to

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/error', stompErrorCallback, {token: accessToken});
```

**User in my case is not authenticated, but from [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-user-destination)**

> While user destinations generally imply an authenticated user, it
>   isn’t required strictly. A WebSocket session that is not associated
>   with an authenticated user can subscribe to a user destination. In
>   such cases the @SendToUser annotation will behave exactly the same as
>   with broadcast=false, i.e. targeting only the session that sent the
>   message being handled.

All this works fine when I am throwing this error from `myHandler` which is my Websocket Handler defined in websocket config.

I have a `ClientInboundChannelInterceptor` which extends `ChannelInterceptorAdapter` which intercepts all the messages in `preSend`.

In case of any exception in this interceptor, I want to throw it back to the user session which sent this message,

```
public class ClientInboundChannelInterceptor extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {
    @Autowired
    @Lazy(value = true)
    @Qualifier("brokerMessagingTemplate")
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message message, MessageChannel channel) throws IllegalArgumentException{
         if(some thing goes wrong)
           throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @MessageExceptionHandler
    @SendToUser(value = "/queue/error",broadcast = false)
    public ApplicationError handleException(RuntimeException message) throws    ApplicationError {
        return  new ApplicationError("test");
    }
}
```

`@MessageExceptionHandler` does not catch this exception. So I tried sending it to the user directly using `simpMessagingTemplate`.

I basically want to do :

```
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(SOMETHING,"/queue/error",e);
```

**SOMETHING** should be the correct username but user is not authenticated in my case, so I can't use `headerAccessor.getUser().getName()`

I have even tried with

```
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(headerAccessor.getHeader("","/queue/error",e, Collections.singletonMap(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.SESSION_ID_HEADER, headerAccessor.getSessionId()));
```

but this is not working.

I have even tried `headerAccessor.getSessionId()` in the place of username, but that does not seem to work.

What is the correct way to do this?

What should I use as username in `convertAndSendToUser`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My initial intuition was correct, sessionId is used as the username in case of unauthenticated user situations, but the problem was with headers.

After few hours of debugging through `@SendToUser` and `simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser()`, I realised that if we use `@SendToUser` headers will be set automatically and we have to explicitly define the headers if we are using `simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser()`.

`@SendToUser` was setting two headers,

> simpMessageType:SimpMessageType.MESSAGE,simpSessionId:sessionId

So I have tried adding the headers,

```
String sessionId = headerAccessor.getSessionId();
Map<String,Object> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
headerMap.put("simpMessageType", SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
headerMap.put("simpSessionId",sessionId);   
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(headerAccessor.getSessionId(),"/queue/error",e,headerMap);
```

It did not work, I have tried giving the headers as `MessageHeaders`

```
String sessionId = headerAccessor.getSessionId();
Map<String,Object> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
headerMap.put("simpMessageType", SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
headerMap.put("simpSessionId",sessionId); 
MessageHeaders headers = new MessageHeaders(headerMap);

simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(headerAccessor.getSessionId(),"/queue/error",e,headers);
```

didn't work either.

After some more debugging I found out the correct way to set the headers, and probably this is the only way to create these headers(from `SendToMethodReturnValueHandler.java`).

```
private MessageHeaders createHeaders(String sessionId) {
    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
    headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);
    headerAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);
    return headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders();
}
```

So finally,

```
String sessionId = headerAccessor.getSessionId();
template.convertAndSendToUser(sessionId,"/queue/error","tesssssts",createHeaders(sessionId));
```

did the trick.

Comment: @Tobia glad that it helped :)

Comment: This work, thanks.
More details: Using Spring Framework 4.3.2.   My client is a Stomp.js Websocket over STOMP.   You need the simpSessionId of the other user that you want sent the message. My client:  stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/bancaria.readcard', function(messageOutput)...  and the server:  messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(targetSessionId, "/queue/bancaria.readcard", message, headers);    I'm not using Spring Security for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `convertAndSendToUser()` only if that user is subscribed to the destination:

   ```
   super.convertAndSend(this.destinationPrefix + user + destination, payload, headers, postProcessor);
   ```
2. Where `user` can be just `sessionId` - `headerAccessor.getSessionId()`
3. The `@MessageExceptionHandler` does its work only withing `@MessageMapping` or `@SubscribeMapping`.

See `SendToMethodReturnValueHandler` source code for more info.

Comment: I am not sure why you said that we can't use `convertAndSendToUser()` , but setting headers in the proper manner worked.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. Yes I meant "you can". Was going to say that you can't use ` @MessageExceptionHandler` from the interceptor, because it is to early for it. See my #3